# Deploy IBM Cloud Functions to API in IAM namespace using manifest file

Tags: ibm-cloud, openwhisk, ibm-cloud-functions

When deploying IBM Cloud Functions using a manifest file from the CLI, the API isn't created in the targeted namespace if it's in an IAM-enabled Resource Group, but it works if targeting a Cloud Foundry-based namespace. How can I deploy an API using a manifest file to a namespace inside an IAM-enabled Resource Group?

```sh
$ ibmcloud resource group-create TodoBackendRG
$ ibmcloud fn namespace create TodoBackendNamespace
ok: created namespace TodoBackendNamespace
$ ibmcloud target -g TodoBackendRG
Targeted resource group TodoBackendRG

API endpoint:      https://cloud.ibm.com
Region:            us-south
User:              matthew@example.com
Account:           Matthews Account (blah) <-> blah
Resource group:    TodoBackendRG
CF API endpoint:   https://api.ng.bluemix.net (API version: 2.141.0)
Org:               TodoBackendOrg
Space:             dev
$ ibmcloud fn property set --namespace TodoBackendNamespace
ok: whisk namespace set to TodoBackendNamespace
$ ibmcloud fn deploy -m manifest.yml
Success: Deployment completed successfully.
$ ibmcloud fn api list
ok: APIs
Action                            Verb             API Name  URL
```

The above deployment doesn't fail, but instead of deploying to the namespace `TodoBackendNamespace` in the IAM-enabled Resource Group `TodoBackendRG`, it deploys to the Cloud Foundry-based namespace `TodoBackendOrg_dev`.

If I try to call out the namespace the deployment fails.

```sh
$ ibmcloud fn deploy -n TodoBackendNamespace -m manifest.yml
Error: Deployment did not complete sucessfully. Run `wskdeploy undeploy` to remove partially deployed assets.
servicedeployer.go [1656]: [ERROR_WHISK_CLIENT_ERROR]: Error code: 147: The supplied authentication is not authorized to access 'TodoBackendNamespace/TodoBackendFN'. (code 33f32f829a3d1b88e8bccd440f13ee91): HTTP Response Status: 403 Forbidden HTTP Response Body: {"code":"33f32f829a3d1b88e8bccd440f13ee91","error":"The supplied authentication is not authorized to access 'TodoBackendNamespace/TodoBackendFN'."}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure you are updated to the lastest version of cli. Currently, it is 1.0.36. Using `ibmcloud plugin install cloud-functions` will update your functions CLI to the latest.

Second, before issuing `ibmcloud fn deploy`, please issue `ibmcloud fn property get` command to get your properties. What is your whisk namespace value? Is it a random string or TodoBackendOrg_dev? If it is TodoBackendOrg_dev, that means you are still target your CF namespace.

Comment: All in all, you will need to to have the latest version of cli and target the IAM namespace before deployment.